# “Should had” usage in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Can I say following sentence? If no, what’s the best alternative. Thanks

> I should had gone but I didn’t.

Comment: A modal can take only a bare infinitive. In your case *have*.

Answer (score 2):

Modal Verbs: can, may, should, shall, will, must, could, might, would, ought.

The word after modal verb is always root word (means no added 's' or past tense or added '-ing').

Had is the past tense of have and has, however, we don't use 'should has' even for 'she'. For example, she would have... (NOT she would has). Thus, always use 'should have'.